# Background update in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

We have a database table with created datetime and status flag. We would like to update the status flag to the next status if the created date time has elapsed by 30 minutes without any user intervention. How can we achieve this in php.

Comment: cron tasks in *nix, and windows task scheduler for...windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a php file that does this status change in the database and program to execute it every 30 minutes with cron (Linux) or Task Scheduler (Windows).

Comment: here is a simple crontab line:
*/5 * * * * /path_to_php/php -f my.php > /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

You have to think carefully about how you design and use your database. Sometimes things are made overly complicated when they don't need to. For instance, in this case you could use a 'datetime' in your table indicating the start time. Any PHP script can now check whether or not the start time started 30 minutes ago, only when this information is actually needed. No need for a flag, cron jobs, etc.